# Recursive backtracking sometimes missing a tile?

Tags: c#, algorithm, ai, procedural-generation

I have a basic recursive backtracking algorithm for a maze. It pretty much works but occasionally leaves some tiles in the corners untouched. This is the recursive function:

```
void GenerateMaze(Coordinate tilePos)
    {
        Debug.Log("MazeGen");
        tileMap[tilePos.x, tilePos.y].visited = true;
        Shuffle<Coordinate>(directions);
        foreach(Coordinate d in directions)
        {
            if (tilePos.x + d.x >= 0 && 
            tilePos.x + d.x < mapWidth && 
            tilePos.y + d.y >= 0 &&
            tilePos.y + d.y < mapHeight)
            {
                if (!tileMap[tilePos.x + d.x, tilePos.y + d.y].visited)
                {
                    Carve(tilePos, d);
                    GenerateMaze(new Coordinate(tilePos.x + d.x, tilePos.y + d.y));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how the Carve method looks like:

```
private void Carve(Coordinate position, Coordinate direction)
    {
        if (direction.Equals(new Coordinate(-1, 0)))
        {
            tileMap[position.x, position.y].west = true;
            tileMap[position.x + direction.x, position.y + direction.y].east = true;
        }
        else if (direction.Equals(new Coordinate(1, 0)))
        {
            tileMap[position.x, position.y].east = true;
            tileMap[position.x + direction.x, position.y + direction.y].west = true;
        }
        else if (direction.Equals(new Coordinate(0, -1)))
        {
            tileMap[position.x, position.y].south = true;
            tileMap[position.x + direction.x, position.y + direction.y].north = true;
        }
        else if (direction.Equals(new Coordinate(0, 1)))
        {
            tileMap[position.x, position.y].north = true;
            tileMap[position.x + direction.x, position.y + direction.y].south = true;
        }
    }
```

I'm betting on a typo or stupid mistake somewhere but I cannot find it. In my last result `tileMap[4,4]` stayed untouched without any walls. But the algorithm does backtrack as I often end up with dead ends. It does not happen often and up till now only on the sides.

Below is an example where two `tiles` on the bottom right have not been carved in too.
[image]

Here is another one without walls, this time 3 unconnected `tiles` in another corner of the maze.
[image]

Anyone can find whats wrong?

Comment: Could you add screen shots (upload to imgur with the stack exchange tool) to show us what you have and what you expect? Reading a couple of chunks of code sometimes is harder when we don't see the intent.

Comment: omg put some parentheses to group expressions in that if statement in the first code block

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I Cannot right now. But it creates a simple maze, except sometimes it does not pass all the tiles on the grid and those tiles will not be "carved" and thus unreachable. But since my method is recursive, passes next to these tiles and loops through all directions this should not happen. ---I basically get a full maze most of the time and sometimes a lone tile or two on the edge.

Comment: @Babis and why if I may ask? It is a single group that simply checks if the new location is out of bounds of the array, nothing special.

Comment: Just clarity, no special reason. Sometimes bugs are harder to identify with lack of clarity.  What's exactly going on in Carve function? care to elaborate?

Comment: @Babis Each tile has 4 walls and the carve function carves the walls in between two tiles (the current tile `position` and the `direction`).

Comment: My best tip in your situation would be to print stuff to console and track what's going on and why it's not happening. Also, you'll want to be able to reproduce the bug at will so you'll have to control your shuffle (pseudo-random number generator) to always produce the same sequence.

Comment: That is what I am doing.  I also have a seed that gives me the unwanted result. But it must be something simple I'm overlooking. It's a basic recursive backtracking maze. Debugging in Unity3D seems not very functional either.

Comment: Try adding a visual debug marker (a colored dot maybe) to show which tiles were visited - might help zero in on the source of trouble.  Also, is directions a global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question, but looking at it this morning I noticed that the `directions` collection isn't defined in the body of the method, nor passed as an argument. That means, unless its iterator is defined in an unusual way, that every recursive call is using *the same* collection of directions, re-shuffling it on every recursion.

This is a problem because this maze generation algorithm relies on exhaustively trying every direction from the each cell, to ensure we haven't missed visiting any of them.

We do this exhaustive check in a random order to make the maze non-uniform, but for this to work, the random order we choose for a cell has to be *fixed* at the time we start exploring that cell.

Imagine we start exploring a cell and randomly shuffle the `directions` collection into the order [North, East, South, West]. We check North first and find it unvisited, so we carve Northward and recurse and recurse and recurse, re-shuffling our directions each time.

By the time the stack unrolls back to the cell we started from, let's say the `directions` collection is in the order [East, North, South, West]. If we carry trying the second, third, and fourth directions in this list, we'll have completely skipped checking the East direction, since it got swapped into a slot that our local iterator state thinks it already checked!

So, if we're solving this recursively, we need to fix the permuted order we'll check the directions as a local variable that can persist its value in the stack until we resume. That doesn't mean we need to copy arrays all over the place. There are only 24 permutations of four elements into four slots, and we can pack them into a collection of 24 integers:

```
27
30
39
45
54
57
75
78
99
108
114
120
135
141
147
156
177
180
198
201
210
216
225
228
```

You can store this list as a constant, and instead of your shuffle routine, select one random integer from the list, then peel it out into a permutation of the directions like so:

```
int order = orders[Random.Range(0, orders.Length)];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // Peel one value 0-3 off the bottom.
    var direction = directions[order & 3];
    // Chop off the direction we read,
    // to bring the next one to the bottom.
    order >>= 2;

    // ... now use the direction.
}
```